# Nesting 2 Case When Formulas - NetSuite Saved Search

Tags: case, netsuite

I am needing to combine these two CASE WHEN statement for a netsuite saved search. How do I do this?

CASE WHEN {type}='bill' AND {vendeor.altname}='AMERICAN EXPRESS' THEN 'STEP 3 BILL' ELSE 'STEP 1 BILL' END

CASE WHEN {type}='bill payment' AND {vendeor.altname}='AMERICAN EXPRESS' THEN 'STEP 4 BILL PAYMENT' ELSE 'STEP 2 DUMMY PAYMENT' END

Answer (score 0):

You're question is missing some logic but essentially a case statement can have multiple `WHEN` clauses so you're looking for something like:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN xxx THEN 'STEP 1 BILL'
    WHEN yyy THEN 'STEP 2 DUMMY PAYMENT'
    WHEN {type}='bill' AND {vendor.altname}='AMERICAN EXPRESS' THEN 'STEP 3 BILL'
    WHEN {type}='bill payment' AND {vendor.altname}='AMERICAN EXPRESS' THEN 'STEP 4 BILL PAYMENT'
    ELSE 'unconfigured' 
END
```

NOTE: I often write complex case statements in a blank page on a proper editor to make them clearer. If you do that be aware that when you paste it back into the formula field Netsuite has, in the past, stripped the line feeds but didn't replace them with spaces.